# QT: Ui doesn't refresh while Building

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I got a problem with QT Creator. I changed some widgets in my UI-file but when I'm building my program I get the old version without the changes. I already tried these things:

- Clean all
- delete the 'dir'-build-desktop file
- delete the header files in the 'dir'-build-desktop file
- rebuild all

Nothings seems to work out...kind of desperate...anyone got some advice? 
Thank you in advance,

Laurens

Answer (score 3):

Try running `qmake`. (This is an option in the `Build` menu.)

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- did you save your ui file to disk before building?
- building the ui file xxx.ui creates the file ui_xxx.h in the build directory. Does this file have a date in the future? Delete this file and rebuild.
- do you include the correct header file (ui_xxx.h)?